# "so many books as I would like." / "so many books as I would like to have."

Tags: as

> I don’t have so many books **as I would like.**
>
> I don’t have so many books **as I would like to have.**

Am I right that both versions sound good, or only the second one?

Comment: I would replace _so_ with _as_.

Comment: The first one is fine (but with _as many_, as @mdewey suggests).